# How to turn cloudinary image to base64 img synchronously?

Tags: javascript, base64, cloudinary

Pretty much what the post says. I don't want to use an async option and can't seem to find any out of the box cloudinary transformation that will do something like `cloudinaryImg/transform_toBase64,w_20,h_20/123.jpg` (this is an example). This also needs to be on the front end.

Also most of the javascript options seem to only do async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the base64 of the image using its URL.
Here are some resources -

[How can I convert an image into Base64 string using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-can-i-convert-an-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

https://base64.guru/developers/javascript/examples/convert-image

Here is a simple example influenced by the one given [here](https://base64.guru/developers/javascript/examples/encode-remote-file) -

```
var url = 'https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg';

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function () {
  // Create a Uint8Array from ArrayBuffer
  var codes = new Uint8Array(xhr.response);

  // Get binary string from UTF-16 code units
  var bin = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, codes);

  // Convert binary to Base64
  var b64 = btoa(bin);
  console.log(b64); 
};

// Send HTTP request and fetch file as ArrayBuffer
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.send();
```

Comment: This would be an async function would it not?

Comment: @TaylorAustin In the above example, the XHR is processed asynchronously ([default behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#types_of_requests)). The `onload` function _can be_ async (by specifying the `async` keyword), but in any way, it is executed only after the request has been completed.